# Sql to Linq like syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, syntax

How would I write a linq query in C# for the table `SomeTable` where `MyCol` contains all words from a list? Is there some way to easily write a Like statement for this?

I've searched the internet for an answer to my problem, but wasn't able to find things that quite fit. 
In Linq, there is the `contains`, `startsWith`, and `endsWith` methods. These really help if I have an SQL statement like:

```
select * from SomeTable where Col_1 like '%cat' or Col_2 like 'dog%' or Col_3 like     '%Random%'
```

But. What I have is a statement like this:

```
declare @Wild_Name varchar(500) = 'my cat likes dogs'
set @Wild_Name='%'+REPLACE(@Wild_Name,' ','%')
```

This would in effect cause `@Wild_Name` to equal `%my%cat%likes%dogs` and now I'm searching for every one of those words in order with possibly something in between in this statement:

```
select * from SomeTable where MyCol like @WildName
```

A result that can be pulled up by this query is `That's my cat. He really likes black dogs`
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, though there is no "Like" in LINQ.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
string wild_name = "my cat likes dogs";
string test_string = "That's my cat. He really likes black dogs";

bool match = wild_name.Split(' ').All( w => test_string.Split(' ').Contains(w));
```

Pre-splitting test_string would likely provide a performance boost (since you only split once). Also this assumes that all words are space delimited.

To ensure that they come in the correct order:

```
string wild_name = "my cat likes dogs";
string test_string = "That's my cat. He really likes black dogs";

string[] wildStrings = wild_name.Split(' ');
int lastFoundIndex = 0;
bool success = true;
for (int i = 0; i < wildStrings.Length; i++)
{
   if (test_string.Split(' ').Contains(wildStrings[i])
   {
      int findIndex = test_string.Split(' ').IndexOf(wildStrings[i]);
      if (findIndex < lastFoundIndex)
      {
         success = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   else
   {
       success = false;
       break;
   }
}

return success;
```

I couldn't come up with a "pure" LINQ way of doing this, but maybe it will help you come up with some ideas!

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: This won't match in order, will edit to include that.

Comment: I like it @LordTakkera, it helps solve part of my problem. I just need to figure out how to keep the ordering. :)